# UFT-8 or utf-8 ? with or without space at the ending tag ? TAB or Space?

Tags: xml, formatting

I was wondering about:

1. Should I use utf-8 upper or lower case and why or for what cases I need it in upper case ?
2. Is it wrong to remove the ending space of an element to save space ?

   ```
   <myElement myAttribute="0" />
   ```

   to

   ```
   <myElement myAttribute="0"/>
   ```

   That is considering I have Huge files from 200MB to 1GB size
3. Should I use TAB or SPACE if I wanted to save space ?

Comment: Style questions have a problem: While it's generally agreed that consistent style is important, there's never (well, almost never) a single authoritative style.

Comment: I am still wondering about question 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Which context?
2. No, you can't remove that whitespace. At least not if you want to fulfill the XML 1.0 specification.
3. One space character and one tab character need exactly one byte each. Four space characters need 4 bytes but one tab character and an editor with tabsize 4 still needs one byte. Now it's your decision.

Comment: +1 1. well I heard that on MAC utf-8 fails, 2. so there is no problem removing that space on readability on anything ? thanks :)

Comment: "utf-8" in which context? As attribute in the processing instruction? As value for a tag or an attribute?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` my bad, at processing instruction

Comment: You should use the exact name of the character set as defined by IANA, which is "UTF-8" in this case: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets

Comment: The [IANA Character Sets](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) page referenced by joschi says this at the top: "The character set names may be up to 40 characters taken from the printable characters of US-ASCII.  However, no distinction is made between use of upper and lower case letters." Therefore, I conclude that `encoding="UTF-8"` and `encoding="utf-8"` are equivalent in the XML declaration.

Answer (score 0):

> **1. Should I use utf-8 upper or lower case and why or for what cases I need it in upper case ?**

I presume you are referring to the XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

he [IANA Character Sets](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) page says this near the top:

> The character set names may be up to 40 characters taken from the
>   printable characters of US-ASCII. However, no distinction is made
>   between use of upper and lower case letters.

Therefore, I conclude that `encoding="UTF-8"` and `encoding="utf-8"` are equivalent in the XML declaration.

> **2. Is it wrong to remove the ending space of an element to save space?**

```
<myElement myAttribute="0" />

<myElement myAttribute="0"/>

<myElement myAttribute></myElement>
```

Each of these expressions represents an element that has no content. They are all semantically equivalent. In the first expression the space character that precedes `/>` is not significant. (Although frequently you'll see that space character added for style.)

> **3. Should I use TAB or SPACE if I wanted to save space ?**

In the UTF-8 encoding (as well as ASCII), `TAB` and `SPACE` each occupy one byte. So, if you are using multiple `SPACE` characters to indent, replacing each group of `SPACE` characters with a single `TAB` character would save storage space (or reduce the size of the XML document in a network transmission).